# Sort Lucene search results by different fields

Tags: sorting, lucene

I am using Lucene.NET and getting search results sorted by 'Date' field.

Here are some example code of search results sorted by date:

```
var collector = TopFieldCollector.Create(sortByDate, nDocuments, false, true, true, false);
indexSearcher.Search(query, collector);
var scoreDocs = collector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;
```

I need to sort results by some other field which not known after I get the results.

For example, after the initial results which sorted by date, I need to sort by Name/From/etc.

Is it possible sort again the collector/ScoreDocs?

Thanks.

Comment: could you not collect these results into a custom list and sort them by whichever column you choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot sort again scoreDocs because it only contains the top documents, but you can run this query again sorting on a different field.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same thought but need to confirm the best approach.